# Help with summations for discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I'm having a lot of trouble approaching these problems. I could start them but I have no idea how to simplify after expanding them. Any help would be appreciated :)

$$\sum_{i=28}^n (3i^2 - 4i + (5/7^i))$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{2^{n-i+1}}$$

Comment: Do you know $\sum_{i=0}^n i$? $\sum_{i=0}^n i^2$?

Comment: Yes I have the basic summations memorize.

Comment: See my answer below, then (let me know if it's not clear enough, esp. the last part).

Answer (score 1):

- Assuming you know that 
  $$
  \sum_{i=0}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}, \qquad \sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
  $$
  and
  $$
  \sum_{i=0}^n r^i = \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}, \quad r \neq 1
  $$
  then you can rewrite the first sum as
  $$
  \sum_{i=28}^n \left(3i^2 - 4i + \frac{5}{7}^i\right) = \sum_{i=0}^n \left(3i^2 - 4i + \frac{5}{7}^i\right) - \sum_{i=0}^{27} \left(3i^2 - 4i + \frac{5}{7}^i\right)
  $$
  and observe that
  $$
  \sum_{i=0}^n \left(3i^2 - 4i + \frac{5}{7}^i\right) = 
  3\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 - 4\sum_{i=0}^n i + 5\sum_{i=0}^n\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^i.
  $$
  (You can then compute each of the three terms separately.)
- As for the second, a change of indices gives
  $$
  \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{2^{n-i+1}} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n-k+1}{2^k}
  =  (n+1)\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^k}  - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{2^k} 
  $$
  The first term, you can compute using the same expression for $\sum_{k=0}^n r^k$ (be careful with the indices!). The second, one way to compute it is to recognize the derivative of some polynomial of the form $\sum_{k=0}^n x^k$, evaluated at $x=1/2$ (again, with the appropriate bounds).

Comment: For the first one, I'm getting

$$\frac{n(n+1)(2n-3)}{2} + 5\frac{1-\frac{1}{7}^{n+1}}{1-\frac{1}{7}}$$

Is that correct? :/

Comment: To check your result once you have found it, consider using some math tool like[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%282i%5E2+-+4i+%2B+5%2F7%5Ei%29%2C+i%3D0..n): it is not giving any insight in the derivation, but will let you know if you got it right.

Comment: Also, I don't quite understand the second term for the second summation :P

Comment: You have something of the form $\sum_1^n k x^k$.Define the function $f(x) = \sum_{1}^n k x^k = x \sum_{1}^n k x^{k-1}$, and observe that $f(x) = x g^\prime(x)$ for $g(x) =  \sum_{1}^n x^{k} = \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$. So you can have the exact expression of $f$ (by computing $g^\prime)$, and it remains to compute $f(1/2)$.